# In android flow + room, How to monitor a List of Flow

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Helloo,

```
----DAO---
@Transaction
@Query("select * from expenses where date= :date")
suspend fun getExpenseWithTagByDate(date: LocalDate): Flow<List<ExpenseWithTag>>
```

I have a dao code like below. **BUT if I need query two days or more, How can I do it?**

```
fun getEnpenseWithTagByMonth(dates: List<LocalDate>) =
    flow {
        val lists = arrayListOf<Flow<List<ExpenseWithTag>>>()
        dates.forEach {
            val expenses = expenseDao.getExpenseWithTagByDate(it)
            lists.add(expenses)
        }
        emit(lists)
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

then

```
getEnpenseWithTagByMonth(dates).asLiveData()
```

finally i get a type, and it's very terrible:

> `ArrayList<Flow<List<ExpenseWithTag>>>>>`

**How I can write the code with Concise and efficient**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question

> if I need query two days or more, How can I do it?

You could use an `in` query, and then group them.

```
@Query("select * from expenses where date IN (:dates)")
suspend fun getExpenseWithTagByDate(dates: List<LocalDate>): Flow<List<ExpenseWithTag>>
```

```
fun getEnpenseWithTagByMonth(dates: List<LocalDate>): Flow<List<List<ExpenseWithTag>>> {
    return expenseDao.getExpenseWithTagByDate(dates).map { expenses ->
        expenses.groupBy{ expense -> expense.date }.values
    }
}
```

Comment: @Transaction
    @Query("select * from expenses where date in (:dates)")
    fun getExpenseWithTagByDates(dates: List<LocalDate>): Flow<List<ExpenseWithTag>>

the code  is work for me. thanks.

Comment: At first, What I need observe is List<Flow> . 
at use the in keyword , the observe type is Flow.